# android measure different values

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I use the `measure` function like this:

```
final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
holder.mExtraPanel.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
```

And it gives good results on Android 5.0.1 on Samsung S4 but on Nexus 5 Android 6 it's giving me different values  (same screen resolution).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Android 6 the `View.measure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)` is different, so just do this:

```
targetSdkVersion = 23
```